# How to pass value from base adapter to Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview, baseadapter, expandablelistadapter

I have added a button in expandable list view header. On clicking the button I need to pass a value from adapter to activity.

Comment: where is expandable listview and button? I can't see.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17417839/how-to-pass-values-from-adapter-to-activity

Comment: i tried this sample, on clicking the button i need to pass the value from adapter to activity

Comment: i have achieved by adding an interface -- Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add listener or simply use `((YourActivity)mContext).setMyValue();`

The `mContext` is the context from your adapter constructor.

Comment: i am doing in Xamarin Android can you please share the link

Comment: Sorry, I thought its `Java`.

Comment: can you some suggestions for passing the value