# Pass data from Activity in Dialog to another Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-dialog

I have an activity that is shown as Dialog and here is my code

```
/* Open Customer List  */
        final EditText show_customer_list = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cusname);
        show_customer_list.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(add_plan.this, customer_list.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

In that activity I have a code that gets the value from listview

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView position1    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_name);
                TextView position2    = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_address);
                String customer_name    = position1.getText().toString();
                String customer_address = position2.getText().toString();
                finish();
            }
        });

                    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cusname);
                    editText.setText(i.getStringExtra("customer_name"));
                }
            });
```

my problem is how can I pass it to the activity thats behind in my dialog activity

Comment: I suggest you to use intent and extras to send data to other activity.

Comment: I tried that but my activity has a free fill textbox that clear out when i do that

Comment: Try using an interface, [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17419415/7671879).

Comment: @miguelarc dont know how to use it