# Trying to pass a function parameter in Kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, lambda, parameters, field

I have a function:

```
fun test(){
    Timber.d("Button Clicked")
}
```

And I'm trying to pass this function to a fragment. Here is that field inside my fragment.

```
class MyFragment(val layout: Int) : Fragment() {
     var clickEvent1: (() -> Unit)? = null
}
```

And this is how I'm setting this field before beginning fragment transaction.

```
fragment.clickEvent1 = {test()}
```

My goal is to run this function on my button click inside my fragment.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     dialog_option_1.setOnClickListener { clickEvent1 }
}
```

There's an issue with the way I'm doing this because the "test" function does not run. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotiln: pass data from adapter to activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826346/kotiln-pass-data-from-adapter-to-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
dialog_option_1.setOnClickListener(clickEvent1)
```

You need to pass the lambda itself to method, so you should use () parentheses instead of {}, which create a new lambda that just does almost nothing in your case.

Comment: Sadly doesn't work. setOnClickListener() requires View.OnClickListener. clickEvent1 is a (() -> Unit). :(

Comment: Then define clickEvent1 as (View) -> Unit (onClick method receives View parameter)

Comment: Or you can use SAM constructor: `val clickEvent = View.OnClickListener { view -> test() }`

Comment: Alright I got it working with `dialog_option_1.setOnClickListener {clickEvent1?.let { it() }}`, your sulotion seems to work nicely. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can replace `clickEvent1?.let { it() }` with `clickEvent1?.invoke()`.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
dialog_option_1.setOnClickListener { clickEvent1() }
```

if you want to do it like that.