# how to pass value from adapter to activity (in oncreate method) i am getting value bt i want that value to be declared in on create method

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, interface, adapter

mainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

    long ProductId = Long.parseLong(i.getStringExtra("product_id"));
    long CustomerId = 1;
    int sizeId = 1; // this is where i need int value to be passed
    int quantity = 201;
}

//here i am getting this id value successfully bt i want that value to be assigned to sideId int in on create method
@Override
public void onClickCheckbox(Integer id) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(id));
}
```

interface

```
public interface OnSizeClickInterface {
 void onClickCheckbox(Integer id);
}
```

adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.checkBox.setText(pList.get(position).getCode());
    holder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(view -> onSizeClickInterface.onClickCheckbox(pList.get(position).getId()));

}
```

this is where i am passing the value everything works fine! as i mentioned i want that id value to be in on create method
i hope i will get my answer soon!
thanks

Comment: You can use this , its complete https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56826346/kotiln-pass-data-from-adapter-to-activity/56827414#56827414

Comment: yes, but that's what i have already done

Comment: i want to get that passed value in on create method

Answer (score 1):

Make `sizeId` as a global variable and assign the new value in the `onClickCheckbox ()` of the MainActivity, and you can resume your task from there itself such as updating views.

**MainActivity**

```java
private int sizeId = 1;

@Override
public void onClickCheckbox(Integer id) {
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(id));
    sizeId = id;
    // update views if required 
    // Perform any other tasks if required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces can be implements with 2 way, One way you have already implemented and the other way you want to use inside specific method.

You have to change your code.

```
public int sizeId;// Either initialize sizeId=1
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);

    long ProductId = Long.parseLong(i.getStringExtra("product_id"));
    long CustomerId = 1;

    int quantity = 201;

    productSizeAdapter = new ProductSizeAdapter(this, pList, new OnSizeClickInterface() {
        @Override
        public void onClickCheckbox(int id) {
            sizeId = id;//this is where i am getting perfect value 
            //You should use sizeId here because it is click event.
            SizeQuantity sizeQuantity = new SizeQuantity(sizeId, quantity); 

        }
    });
    //If you want to use here than you have to initialized sizeId=1. But I don't think you want to use here, because it will be called only once not every time when clicked
    //SizeQuantity sizeQuantity = new SizeQuantity(sizeId, quantity); 

}
```

Comment: Hello keyur, i tried this and new problem arises here please look at the code i have re-edited